# Why are "i.e." and "e.g." written in lower case with periods, while "NB" is typically written in CAPS with no periods?

Tags: punctuation, orthography, abbreviations, latin, style-manuals

According to my [armchair research on common abbreviations of *nota bene*,](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=NB%2CN.B.%2Cnb%2Cn.b.&year_start=1700&year_end=2019&corpus=26) it appears that *NB* is the most common now, with *N.B.* being more common in centuries past after taking over the "original" *nb* in the early 1700s.  While *n.b.* is the least common by far.  This is very different from *i.e.* and *e.g.*.

Some abbreviations like *etc.* and *et al.* aren't taken down to single letters, but almost every Latin->English abbreviation I know of is lower case, and includes at least one period.  Etymologies I look up just talk about the Latin origins, but don't talk about how the particular glyphs were chosen.

Why is *NB* typically capitalized, and why the common lack of periods?

Comment: The often-swapped i.e. and e.g. sit mid-sentence, whereas NB always begins sentences to announce a key pointer. So that justifies at least the initial initial. And it's a bit like a traffic sign or billboard with capitalized words.

Comment: Something simiilar happens with other abbreviations: QED, PS, QEI, USA, ...

Comment: @Ananias Indeed — it looks like ‘i.e.’ and ‘e.g.’ are the odd ones out that need explaining. (I expect it's just historical accident, but I'd be interested to see any actual evidence.)

Comment: @Ananias There are many, many Latin abbreviations that are normally majusculated, like [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Latin_abbreviations) and [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_classical_abbreviations). Copious examples include *A.D., C.V., D.G., J.D., M.D., M.O., N.P.O., O.D., O.S., Ph.D., P.R.N., R.I.P., S.D.G., Th.D., et hoc genus omne.* :)

Comment: @tchrist: Glad to see you agree with my comment "Something simiilar happens with other abbreviations". Your abundance of examples is ovewhelming, far from my infinitesimal contribution

Comment: Rᴇʟᴀᴛᴇᴅ: [1](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/711), [2](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/11740), [3](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/12872), [4](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/12872), [5](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/14533), [6](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/20680), [7](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/25257), [7](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/25685), [9](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/33226), [10](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/115784), [11](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/477445), [12](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/41828).

Comment: @tchrist is R.I.P. Latin? Most of those examples are titles, right?  Those seem different than _i.e._, _e.g._, _cf_, _ibid_, _et al._, and so on, which are just shorthand words rather than titles.

Comment: @SO_fix_the_vote_sorting_bug [RIP](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/RIP) stands for the Latin ‘Requiescat In Pace’ — it's a happy coincidence* that the English translation ‘Rest In Peace’ has the same initials. (* Well, ‘[peace](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/peace#Etymology)’ is derived from the Latin via Old French and Anglo-Norman, but the other two words, surprisingly, don't seem to be cognate.)

Comment: @gidds I thought *in* in English and Latin are cognate, and [Wiktionary thinks so too](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/in#Latin)

Comment: @Henry Hmmm, Wiktionary seems a little confused: [its etymology](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/in#Etymology_1) for the English word ‘in’ (which is what I'd checked) gives only Middle English, Old English, and Proto-Germanic — even though, as you indicate, the entry for the Latin word further down that same page explicitly claims they're cognate! (Either way, the third word does _not_ seem to be cognate, so there's still _some_ element of luck involved.)

Comment: I never know what the hell to do when I want to start a sentence with ie or eg (or i.e. or e.g.). Ie, this sentence.

Comment: The printers and editors just do it to assert their power and to make us feel dumb. There's no good reason for it, and you should feel free to capitalize, punctuate, and abbreviate as you see fit. Everybody else does, after all.

Comment: @Fattie  Those abbreviations shouldn't be used to start a sentence.  At least that's the modern practice. The abbreviation **i.e.** is equivalent to English "that is", and it introduces a phrase or a clause that is "tacked on" to a statement  in order to clarify it, something that doesn't really stand on its own as a "thought" in its own right; and the abbreviation **e.g.** which is equivalent to English "for example", is normally used in a parenthetic remark.

Comment: I agree with you TimR and nicely put. Unfortunately though it's pretty common to, let's say, take a whole sentence break rather than merely a comma when you run on a parenthetical remark. That is, people annoyingly now do this all the time. For example, I've just done it again. Perhaps my rule to self should be, ok, but you can't get away with that if using the abbreviations.

Answer (score 40):

Here is what *The Chicago Manual of Style* has to say:

> NB, n.b.     *nota bene*, take careful note (capitals are
> illogical but often used for emphasis)
>
> <sub>Source: [*The Chicago Manual of
> Style*](https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/home.html) (login
> required)</sub>

It's not a terribly satisfying answer, but such is often the case when *style* is the operative word.

Comment: Doesn't the style follow the English words we would naturally choose instead? We write i.e. and e.g. after a comma, so treat them the way we would treat "that is" following a comma; and we usually write NB as the beginning of a sentence.

Comment: @Chaim — Then why not *Nb* or *N.b.* at the beginning of a sentence? Would you start a sentence with *For Example* with a capital *E*? This is style, not logic.

Comment: Well I would say that the truth lies somewhere in the middle. I agree that if we were treating NB as two English words, Nb would make more sense than NB. But Nb looks pretty awful, and the analogy to ordinary English seems relevant although imperfect. Can you think of many analogies to Nb, with just the first letter capitalized?

Comment: I also find the lack of periods odd. N.b. would be less illogical, perhaps.

Comment: @TinfoilHat, the only way I can think of capitalizing both words like you mention, would be as in the following: _FOR EXAMPLE._  But I agree, this whole thing probably just comes down to style, and _NB_ has won out, for now.

Comment: @Chaim — Here are a few examples from *CMOS*'s "Miscellaneous technical abbreviations": Bps/bytes per second. Btu/British thermal unit. eV/electron volt. kWh/kilowatt-hour. Mbps/megabits per second...

Comment: @SO_fix_the_vote_sorting_bug I think _FOR EXAMPLE_ is kind of exactly why it’s _NB_; seems to be what _The Chicago Manual of Style_ suggests. One might not have actually written _FOR EXAMPLE_ just because that is a lot of capitals, but for _NB_ it’s just two, or one if, as it often is, it starts a sentence.

Comment: @Chaim the element niobium? :)

Comment: Niobium: do not confuse chemical symbols with other unrelated abbreviations.

Comment: @SO_fix_the_vote_sorting_bug People do often write NOTE in all capitals for emphasis.

Comment: Chaim and others: "style is style".  The C.M.O.S is *proscriptive*, not *descriptive*. (In total contrast to the famous dictum which opens the intro to the original OED!) The CMOS is stating, as a dictum: "If, in fact, you wish to use the CMOS style, for example you're a paid write working for a newspaper which states 'We use the CMOS style', then use 'n.b.'."  And that's that.  It's just a "style" like choosing a type face for your newspaper. You may or may not wish to use that "style". If your school / newspaper / company chooses a certain style (say CMOS), you have consistency.

Comment: @TinfoilHat The metric abbreviations have some internal consistency driven by the need for unique identifiers, IF you know what they mean and know what the rules are: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/104977/169106 E.g. MWh and mWh -- h for hour is just a normal unit (lower case), W for watt because even though "watt" the unit is lower case it comes from a proper name (I don't make the rules, just relate them), and M for a positive exponent (mega) vs. m for a negative exponent (milli). "k" for kilo is a special exception because K for Kelvin was already used.

Comment: @TinfoilHat In other words, of the several examples on the table of abbreviations in mixed case, all are scientific jargon. And you think that they warrant putting NB into mixed case? I agree with everyone repeating that this is a point of style; but where does that agreement get us?

Answer (score 7):

*NB* or *N.B.* usually introduces a sentence, whereas *i.e.* and *e.g.* usually come in the middle of one.

Answer (score 3):

It's likely that that all caps version is favored because of the intent. "Nota bene" apparently means, "pay extra attention!" and, since n.b! looks weird and jarring, the all caps was chosen for emphasis.

Comment: "looks weird and jarring"? That would be because we're not used to it, so it's a circular argument.

Answer (score 3):

I checked some of the style guides in my library to see what they had to say about the preferred form of n.b/nb/N.B./NB, and this is what they had to say (sources are arranged in chronological order, oldest to newest).

From Bergen Evans & Cornelia Evans, *A Dictionary of Contemporary American Usage* (1957):

> **n.b.** This is an abbreviation of the Latin words *nota bene* and means "note well."

From Wilson Follett, *Modern American Usage: A Guide* (1966):

> abbreviations. 1. The modern tendency in scholarship as well as popular works is to replace the Latin abbreviations by English ones; for example, ... *note* for ***N.B.***

From *Words into Type*, third edition (1974):

> The following Latin abbreviations, including some seen only in older works, are not often appropriate to text except parenthetically but are useful in footnote material:
>
> **N.B.** (*nota bene), mark well*

From *Warriner's English Grammar and Composition, Fifth Course* (1977):

> ***N.B.*** *note well* (from the Latin *nota bene*); always italicized or underlined.

From *[Merriam-]Webster's Standard American Style Manual* (1985):

> **Latin Words and Phrases**
>
> **25.** Words and phrases derived from Latin are commonly abbreviated in contexts where readers can reasonably be expected to recognize them. They are punctuated, not capitalized, and usually not italicized.
>
> > [Examples:] etc. | i.e. | e.g. | viz. | eta al. | pro tem.

Although this style guide omits any direct mention of *nota bene*, it seems fair to infer from the prescriptive and categorical approach to the topic of Latin abbreviations that it would endorse the form n.b.

From Stuart Miller, *Concise Dictionary of Acronyms and Initialisms* (1988):

> **n.b.** *Nota bene* (Latin: "note well")

From Robert Hendrickson, *The Facts on File Dictionary of Word and Phrase Origins*, second edition (1997):

> **N.B.** This is the abbreviation used for the Latin nota bene, "note well, take notice," often used in literary and scholarly works. Voltaire told of how a commentator on Lucretius by the name of Creech noted on his manuscript: "N.B. Must hang myself when I have finished." According to Voltaire, "He kept his word, that he might have the pleasure [of committing suicide] like Lucretius. Had he written upon Ovid, he would have lived longer."

From Joseph Gibaldi, *MLA Style Manual and Guide to Scholarly Publishing*, second edition (1998):

> **NB** take notice (from Lat. *nota bene*; always capitalized)

From *The Oxford Dictionary for Writers and Editors* (2000):

> **NB** New Brunswick, North Britain, (Lat.) *nota bene* (mark well)

According to this Oxford style guide, "n.b." stands for "no ball" in cricket.

From Martin Manser, *The Facts on File Dictionary of Foreign Words and Phrases* (2002):

> **nota bene** LATIN {mark well} *verb phrase* note well, observe particularly. ~*abbreviated* forms **n.b., N.B.**

From Andrea Lunsford, *The St. Martin's Handbook*, fifth edition (2003):

> ***Latin abbreviations***
>
> In general, avoid these abbreviations except when citing sources:
>
> ...
>
> **N.B.** note well (*nota bene*)

From Bryan Garner, *Garner's Modern American Usage*, second edition (2003):

> **N.B.** is the abbreviation for the Latin nota bene (= note well; take notice).

And from *The Chicago Manual of Style*, sixteenth edition (2010):

> **NB, n.b.** *nota bene*, take careful note (capitals are illogical but often used for emphasis)

---

The raw vote totals from these reference guides (counting both options offered by CMoS sixteenth edition and by Manser) is as follows:

- **nb** 0 votes
- **n.b.** 4 votes (plus one prescriptive guideline that would seem to require it), ranging from 1957 to 2010
- **N.B.** 7 votes (including one specifying that it should always be italicized or underlined), ranging from 1966 to 2003
- **NB** 3 votes, ranging from 1998 to 2010

Opposition to italicizing the Latin abbreviations thus seems to have begun at an early date, with little counterargument. Both the *n.b.* and *N.B.* forms of that abbreviation have had their adherents among style guides across the years, without pressing the rival punctuated form to the periphery. And *NB* has emerged relatively late—an unsurprising development, given the more general trend toward punctuationless abbreviations in recent years. Perhaps the more forward-looking question would be, By what date are *i.e.* and *e.g.* likely to lose their periods in standard usage?

Comment: [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/nb) has nb as a variant of NB; so does the [Longman Business Dictionary](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/nb). [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/nota-bene) gives four permutations (0 or 2 periods; twinned lower or upper case). Some dictionaries give regional caveats (period dropping less likely in the States).

Answer (score 0):

The literal answer to your question is, simply:

- Literal answer to your question: there is no logical reason whatsoever.

In the question, you have excellently shown that the most popular variation, changes, over time and place.

**Everyone has explained, at length, very properly, reasonable "logical" quasi-arguments for each.**

It's just like asking "What is the logical reason laser become a word but VIP remains an acronym in English (but in Germany people pronounce it as a word, and we may do so in the future in English) ?".  The answer is "there is no logical reason."

Indeed, it's just like asking "What is the logical reason spelling S of word W?"

If (you happen to want to), you would use the most common styling seen in your milieu. This is why newspapers, universities, professional groups, etc, (sometimes) state "We use style _ _ _".

Comment: The default definition of 'acronym' classes 'laser', 'NASA' and 'ISA' as acronyms (of which the first has certainly entered the lexicon) but 'VIP', 'BBC' as initialisms ('spelled out'). And CMOS's '(capitals are illogical but often used for emphasis)' is a 'logical reason', as you concede. I don't see how 'there is no logical reason whatsoever' sits alongside this; you seem to be saying CMOS is incorrect here.

Comment: Hi EA, any style manual is not "correct or incorrect".  It is literally a style manual.  (Much as corporations will have a "style manual" which states, the logo must be XYZ color, the typeface you use must be XYZ color and so on.) Those things are not "correct or incorrect" they are a stated style. Sure, style manuals may include as an addendum the reason for their thinking.  My post is very clear (and I'm so modest about that :) ) and I'm really just repeating myself.

Comment: Regarding the CMOS. and "nb".  (1) The CMOS is poorly written.  (2) The CMOS is very poor conceptually (for example, for color/colour the suggestion is: "go with your local dictionary!!)  (3) It's a very "soft" style manual, it should be titled "The Chicago Interesting Thoughts On Spelling And Stuff"!  :) (4) Regarding "nb", my reading of their entry is "use nb; NB is a bit illogical. As usual since this is the CMOS, you now have no idea what to do!" (5) If you have a different reading of their entry, that's fine. I think their entry is weak, but moreover, style manuals are just style manuals.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say *why* both are used, but I can say which is more common:

According to [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=NB%2CN.B.&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3&case_insensitive=true), **NB** has been more frequently used that N.B. since c. 1960.

(And, considering casing, ["n.b." is hardly used at all](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=N.B.%2CN.b.%2Cn.b.&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3).)

Comment: I'm not sure that Google Ngram is to be trusted here. I see results like "NB-IoT" and other false positives. On the first page of results, I don't actually see *any* true positives. Maybe using a different corpus tool such as [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) would help, maybe not—at least with that you could check the results to account for false positives.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there's some historical reason for it. But mostly, I think, it's just convention. There are lots of things in language that are the way they are just because many people over a long period of time have done them that way. You might as well ask, "Why is the word for a domesticated canine 'dog' and not 'ariwinkle'?" It just is.

Okay, I say this whimsically. If there was some good logical reason or at least pattern why some abbreviations are written in caps and others in small letters it would be helpful to people learning that language. But I think there just ... isn't.

Comment: But this has already been said.